# Coq intros syntax

Tags: syntax, coq

Could someone please explain the `intros` syntax below?

```
Lemma is_single_nBTP : forall t, is_single_nBT t = true -> exists n : nat, t = Leaf n.
Proof.
intros [ nleaf | nnode t1 t2] h.
exists nleaf.
reflexivity.
...
```

Where `nBT` is a nat binary tree, and `is_single_nBT` is a function which returns `true` when `t` is a leaf.

(This example is from this [lecture](http://www.di.ens.fr/~zappa/teaching/coq/ecole11/summer/lectures/lec5.pdf).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[A | B]` is a disjunction pattern.  It is the same idea as case analysis in functional programming languages.

In this case you are creating two subgoals.  One where `t` is known to be a leaf with the natural number `nleaf` as its argument, and another where `t` is introduced as a `Node` with the arguments `nnode`, `t1`, and `t2`.

Either way another argument `h : is_single_nBT ? = true` is introduced where `?` is either `Leaf nleaf` or `Node nnode t1 t2`.

Comment: Could I also use the `case` tactic?

Comment: You can also have a look at the 'intro pattern' part of the documentation and use this with other tactics. I use it a lot with induction and destruct. For example when you do induction over a natural number, you can do ``induction n as [ | p hi]`` to directly name the predecessor and the induction hypothesis.